# How to use rowspan with PugJS whilst extracting variables from a JSON object

Tags: html-table, pug

I have a json object representing a list of teams and each team has three players. I am using express / pug to create table data.

The input structure is like this:

```
{ teams: [
  team: <string>,
  rank: <number>,
  members: [
    name: <string>,
    nationality: <string>,
    age: <number>,...
]
],...}
```

I can see how to generate the cells where the team and all three members are across one row using two each statements:

```html
              each val1 in teams
                tr
                  td #{val1.team}
                  td #{val1.rank}
                    each val2 in val1.members
                      td
                      td #{val2.name}
                      td #{val2.nationality}
                      td #{val2.age}
```

Resulting in one row per team.

```
|----------|---------–|--------|-----------|-----|--------|-----------|-----|--------|-----------|-----|
|   Team   |   Rank   | Name   |Nationality| Age |  Name  |Nationality| Age |  Name  |Nationality| Age |
|----------|---------–|--------|-----------|-----|--------|-----------|-----|--------|-----------|-----|
```

But I want to have the three team members above each other like this:

```
|----------|---------–|--------|-----------|-----|
|          |          | Name   |Nationality| Age |
|          |          |--------|-----------|-----|
|  Team    |   Rank   | Name   |Nationality| Age |
|          |          |--------|-----------|-----|
|          |          | Name   |Nationality| Age |
|----------|---------–|--------|-----------|-----|
```

this could be done using rowspan cells, but I can't figure out how to map the variables.

```html
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Team</td>
<td rowspan="3">Rank</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Nationality</td>
<td>Age</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Nationality</td>
<td>Age</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Nationality</td>
<td>Age</td>
</tr>
```

How can I map the json object in PugJS to generate the layout?

regards
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  It's a matter of getting the indentation right in pug and inserting the rows for each player.  Here's a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/pacific202/pen/WNwwKyN) with the table generated live.

```
table
  each team in teams
    tr
      td(rowspan= team.members.length + 1)= team.team
      td(rowspan= team.members.length + 1)= team.rank
    each player in team.members
      tr
        td= player.name
        td= player.nationality
        td= player.age
```

Comment: Thank you Graham! I did not know that rowspan can work in this way. - I was  trying to create  team  and player 1 cells on the first row. Splitting the ```tr``` and spanning one more row is a great solution.

Comment: @Graham I didn't realize it was just an indentation issue, or else I would have just edited. Thanks for revising. Upvoted as this is cleaner than my other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use a [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) element to section off each team, then you can conditionally render the "team" and "rank" cells only in the first row. Setting [`rowspan="0"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan) on these cells will make them expand the full extent of their `tbody` section.

Here's a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/os/pen/jOqqgpL?editors=1000) forked from Graham's pen.

```
table
  each team in teams
    tbody
      each player, i in team.members
        tr
          if (i == 0)
            th(rowspan='0', scope='row')= team.team
            td(rowspan='0')= team.rank
          td= player.name
          td= player.nationality
          td= player.age
```

Given some data, the above will render:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="0" scope="row">Aberdeen United</th>
      <td rowspan="0">1</td>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Ireland</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Scotland</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charles</td>
      <td>Wales</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Sean, viewing this answer on an iPad - the table is not rendering correctly - Bruce and Charles are in column 1

Comment: Interesting! That sounds like a bug with iOS Safari

Comment: MacOS safari too. Works on MacOS Chrome and MacOS Firefox